# How to get all the points' longitude and latitude values in a polyline

Tags: google-polyline

I have an encoded polyline, this is the content:

```
kbwyFyycpDiEhA~QnIvYTlSvk@pK_CjaBte@fxApKah@mmBqIoh@aEgEot@iS_To[mSoEaLu[mv@fQuKoRiEkc@aOkYgr@NiVlQySlDsHwIez@g]aU`J`AnO{InBsEuQ~G_Z_ScKwO_`@uScMyXhEuUre@c]fOuQfl@kDsCwAoRaj@v_@_FdNuB|YwZ|[wDnSeJvJ}MwHuRiu@cW}`@oByXgJ{Gc\fW_S_G_Qx@yGtMy[fGaEjL_ViG}|@g|ArZom@dKgCE}FeSoTcWuM}v@cSqb@cb@gP_IwX_l@aJcd@qTqUip@sM_ClAbBrEwEj@mE{FvE`GfEk@uAoEhByNDvKfr@xO|RlTrI~b@xYzm@zO`Hbb@ra@zmAx`@|TlWYlEuIxAiF`IuSvg@tZdb@tVjk@|_@|TkBrH_E_E`AfOjFrLqGAmLtXuR`QyAhIt@lJhHfJ}ChDrDtLwEzRtUtw@cPdNwD~Lj@zXjQbU~QjJjCpYrHbEj@dJnTtGnG~Fn@`IhaAqDv_@ai@dJgYjWeIz[ud@z]_QjAqEyEu[|H_Pna@k_@v{AhLr~A}GhE`HnH~m@jJzSve@p]re@jO~y@oScIg@iBiNvEqIuN{`@rEsNl`@iJmTyIxD[
```

How can I find the longitude and latitude values for all the points in the polyline?

I used Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility but with this I get the values point by point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Interactive [Polyline Encoder Utility](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polyline-utility/polylineutility), you can already get the latitude and longitude values using the **"Decode Polyline"** button . Under the **"Locations List"** box you should see all the coordinates for the polyline. Those points in the Locations List box are already the **latitude** and **longitude** values that you need.